# Add weight parameter in custom module

Tags: drupal-7

I created a content type and it's have many nodes. And write custom module for show on frontpage.

My nodes order:

```php
 $themeurl = '/drupal/'.path_to_theme().'/images';
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `node`
            LEFT JOIN `field_data_field_anasayfa_catwalk` ON `field_data_field_anasayfa_catwalk`.`entity_id` = `node`.`nid`
            WHERE type = 'designers_albums'
            AND `node`.`status` = 1
            AND `node`.`language` = '".$language->language."'
            AND `field_data_field_anasayfa_catwalk`.`field_anasayfa_catwalk_value` = 1
            ORDER BY `node`.`created` ASC";
```

But now, installed Weight module and want sort by weight. How can i change this option? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Entities(nodes) weights are stored in `weight_weights` database table.
You can try that query

```php
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM `node`
        LEFT JOIN `field_data_field_anasayfa_catwalk` ON `field_data_field_anasayfa_catwalk`.`entity_id` = `node`.`nid`
        LEFT JOIN `weight_weights` AS w ON w.entity_id=`node`.`nid`
        WHERE type = 'designers_albums'
        AND `node`.`status` = 1
        AND `node`.`language` = '".$language->language."'
        AND `field_data_field_anasayfa_catwalk`.`field_anasayfa_catwalk_value` = 1
        ORDER BY w.weight, `node`.`created` ASC";
```

Btw, in future you should consider learning Drupal database abstraction layer or EntityFieldQuery.

Comment: Try this for last line:
`ORDER BY w.weight DESC, `node`.`created` ASC";`